# regex - match pattern of alternating characters

Tags: regex

I want to match patterns of alternating lowercase characters.

```
ababababa -> match
```

I tried this

```
([a-z][a-z])+[a-z]
```

but this would be a match too

```
ababxyaba
```

Comment: "Alternating" or just "uneven number" of chars? If the latter, enclose the pattern with `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: what do you mean by alternating lowercase characters ?

Comment: a string containing an alternation of two of the same characters - > xyxyxyxy but not xyxyxyabxyxy

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use this regex with 2 back-reference to match alternating lowercase letters:

```
^([a-z])(?!\1)([a-z])(?:\1\2)*\1?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/unaowS/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `([a-z])`: Match first letter in capturing group #1
- `(?!\1)`: Lookahead to make sure we don't match same letter again
- `([a-z])`: Match second letter in capturing group #3
- `(?:\1\2)*`: Match zero or more pairs of first and second letter
- `\1?`: Match optional first letter before end
- `$`: End