# Regexp for positions of runs of alternating characters

Tags: python, regex

I would like to find multiple regions within a string (in my case, a DNA sequence) that have the characters C and G alternating, in any order:

```
str = "ANNNTGCGCCCCGCGGTGCGNNT"
            ^^^^  ^^^^  ^^^
pos    01234567890123456789012
       0         1         2
```

Above I've marked the G/C C/G repeating regions, so I'm looking for a regexp that reports a list of start & end coords like `(5:8, 11:14, 17:19)` or alternatively, using half-closed intervals that report the position immediately after the end of each region `(5:9, 11:15, 17:20)`.

Ideally this would also be case-insensitive. Any suggestions gratefully accepted.

Edit - I'm happy to use any programming language implementation (e.g. Python's `re` module) to extract the positions.

Comment: A regex returns the matched text, how do you want to get the coords? Are you using a programming language? Are you looking for a pattern like `(?:CG)+C?|(?:GC)+G?` https://regex101.com/r/Vg1K8y/1

Comment: Good point. In my case I'm using the Python `re` module, but solutions in other languages are fine too.

Comment: Does a single "GC" count as "alternating" already?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [regex - match pattern of alternating characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45504400/regex-match-pattern-of-alternating-characters)

Comment: @AdrianHHH - thanks for the link to the existing SO answer: it isn't quite the same, although it's similar. Other answers here tackle this specific task and have some efficiency considerations, so I'm going with those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?=GC|CG)G?(?:CG)*C?
```

This matches :

- `(?=GC|CG)` : a lookahead for either `GC` or `CG` to ensure we have at least two characters (since all other parts are optional)
- `G?` : an optional `G`
- `(?:CG)*` : zero or more of `CG`;
- `C?` : an optional `C`

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3xCS8W/1)

In python you can use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) to iterate the search, grabbing the [`span`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.span) from each match object:

```py
s = "ANNNTGCGCCCCGCGGTGCGNNT"
res = [m.span() for m in re.finditer(r'(?=GC|CG)G?(?:CG)*C?', s, re.I)]
```

Output:

```
[(5, 9), (11, 15), (17, 20)]
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this might miss a single `GC`, so @the-fouth-bird 's answer catches this?

Comment: I've corrected the regex. I think this is a little more efficient than @Thefourthbird regex

Comment: I think it also depends on the length of the content, see https://regex101.com/r/7hxTIF/1 But nice one :-)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Interesting, yours does do better for longer sequences. Must spend some time in the debugger...

Comment: @Thefourthbird I looked in the debugger, and what it is is that my regex is more efficient at discarding things that don't match where yours is more efficient at processing the actual matches. So for a string like `ANNNTGCGCCCCGCGGTGCGNNT` mine wins as there are more potential matches to be discarded, but for a string like `CGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCG` yours wins because it is more efficient at matching sequences. So the result will definitely be data dependent.

Comment: This is only because Thefourthbird's branches start with a group. If you change the pattern to: `CG(?:CG)*C?|GC(?:GC)*G?` where each branch starts with a literal string, it will win whatever the scenario: https://regex101.com/r/t5QSqv/1

Comment: @Nick: No, you test one with the Python re engine and the other with PCRE2. Test them with the same regex engine.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte oh, my mistake, sorry. Perhaps you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @the-fourth-bird, `(?:CG)+C?|(?:GC)+G?` will do it when wrapped in a function that returns start and end of matches. E.g. in Python:

```
import re
s = "ANNNTGCGCCCCGCGGTGCGNNT"
print([
    (m.start(), m.end())
    for m in re.finditer(r"(?:CG)+C?|(?:GC)+G?", s, re.IGNORECASE)
])
```

Comment: `m.span()` will return the same as `(m.start(), m.end())`

Comment: Note that you can accept your own answer.  Also see Casimir et Hippolyte comments to my answer for an even better solution